# Save and load variables using shelve

Tags: python, variables, shelve

I'm trying to implement a code that will generate a lot of scenarios. This scenarios will be executed after by a 3 different simulators.

I'm saving my scenarios in a file using shelve. My code is like this:

```
def save_variables(I, T, R, C, lambd, K, iteraction):
    filename='/folder/shelve_{}.out'.format(iteraction)
    my_shelf = shelve.open(filename,'n')
    for key in dir():

        try:
            my_shelf[key] = locals()[key]
        except TypeError:
            pass
    my_shelf.close()
```

and I'm loading data in each simulators like this:

```
    my_shelf = shelve.open(filename)
    my_shelf = shelve.open(filename)
    for key in my_shelf:
        globals()[key]=my_shelf[key]
    my_shelf.close()
```

This part works great. My problem is:

If I run all the code together, in the same terminal of execution, for example, first the scenario_generator, after the simulator_1, after simulator_2 and at least simulator_3, in the same line of execution, the codes works great.

But if I run only the scenario_generator in one terminal and start each simulation in other 3 differents terminals of execution, I receive the follow error:

```
Number of arguments: 2 arguments.
Argument List: on
Iteraction 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 53, in <module>
    onets.onets(i)
  File "/Users/simulator_1.py", line 31, in simulator_1
    n = [[0 for x in range(I+1)] for y in range(T+1)] 
NameError: name 'T' is not defined
```

I understand with this notification that was not possible to read the data saved by shelved. But the files was in folder. Someone knows how I can fix this problem?

P.S.: Is important to me execute in this way (separately) because I should start the 3 simulator as the same time, in different terminals of execution. This will provide a big economy of execution time to have my results.

thanks everyone.

Comment: Is it possible that the scenario computation is slow and some simulation tries to read a key that is not there yet because the scenario has not yet closed the file? (so there is no guarantee that the file is synced). Try to `.sync() after each write then.

Comment: @progmatico it is not possible, because I'm finish the first step (scenario_generation) before start the simulators. all the scenarios are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Without being sure, I suspect you are not storing all the variables you think you are in the shelve.

When the steps are together in a single script, if some values are not written in the shelve, you won't notice because you explicitely silent the TypeError` exception.

This is not recommended as errors go unnoticed. You probably made it exactly to avoid some error that was happening.

Because the scripts are together in the same file they share the same global scope.
When you read the values back into the global scope, and some values are missing, you are probably covered by the original values in that same global scope.

So you miss some values, but when you need them they were already there in global scope to be read from.

With separate files there is no more a common global scope. Any missing value will cause an error.

Remove the `pass` and make the `except` clause print the current key and value to check for missing keys.

Other than that I see no problem in generating file data to read later from whatever different processes/scripts like you described (given there are no cache/sync trouble and you open the files for reading only)